# Explain Soutput Schunk -block when switched from article to scrreprt

Tags: sweave, r, xtable

When I zwitched from article to `\documentclass[fontsize=2pt]{scrreprt}`, I am getting around the xtable -things:

```
\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Soutput}
...
\end{Schunk}
\end{Soutput}
```

**Trial (code [here](http://pastie.org/3878580))**

```
$ R CMD Sweave code.Rnw
$ pdflatex code.tex          # or if you get the Schunk/Soutput, rm manually
$ evince code.pdf
```

How can I force the new package not to output that kind of Schunk/Soutput -block? It is slow to remove them, otherwise not displaying the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think the document class is relevant; instead of `<<echo=False>>=`, you should use `<<echo=FALSE, results=tex>>=` to tell Sweave that the output will be tex code which should not be wrapped in the `Soutput` environment.

Comment: Worked! Thank you +1. I did dot realize the article -class handled this thing implicitly, well always something to learn, better make things more explicit in the future by this.